# Troubleshooting js errors on word guess game

Tags: javascript

New to programming and trying to complete a word guess game. I'm running into an error with my for loops where jslint is telling me the problem is "use strict'. I get an undefined error message on the console. Can't quite understand why even after extensive googling.

Below is my js and corresponding html at the bottom. Any help would be SO appreciated!

---

```
var randomWordArr = ['Tyrannosaurus', 'Stegosaurus', 'Velociraptor'];

//choose random word from the dino array
var randomWord = randomWordArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomWordArr.length)];

var s;
var count = 0;

var answerArray = [];


function startGame() {
  // Set up the answer array
  for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = "_";
  }

  s = answerArray.join(" ");
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = s;
}

function Letter() {
  //get the letter typed in the box
  var letter = document.getElementById("letter").value;

  //make sure we have a guess(can add more checks liek only letters, etc)
  if (letter.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
      if (randomWord[i] === letter) {
        //assign it to letter
        answerArray[i] = letter;
      }
    }

    count++;
    document.getElementbyId("counter").innerHTML = "No. of clicks " + count;
    document.getElementbyId("answer").innerHTML = answerArray.join(" ");
  }
}

onload = "startGame()";
```

```
<form id="hangmanForm">
<input id="letter" type="text">
<input type="button" value="letter" onClick="Letter()" />
     <p id="answer"></p>
     <p id="counter"></p>
     <p id="stat"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error?

Comment: `document.getElementbyId is not a function` It's exactly as the error says. Capitalization matters in programming

Comment: @JordanS the errors read:
       
at line 14, character 3**Missing 'use strict' statement.**
for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {

Comment: at line 14, character 8**Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function.**
for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have used getElementbyId() in your javascript.  This should be getElementById(), that is, it should have an uppercase *B* for *By*.

Hence, the code should be:

```
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "No. of clicks " + count;
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answerArray.join(" ");
```

To allow the code to run you need to call the StartGame function near the end of the java script using the following line of code:

```
startGame();
```

You can find a working version of the code [here](https://repl.it/repls/ForthrightSweetSupport).

A further improvement that can be made in terms of the game itself is that the letter text box can be cleared after each entry so that it is ready for the next input.  This can be done as follows:

```
document.getElementById("letter").value = "";
```

I have added this to solution provided in my link above.

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic. Commenting is appropriate; flagging/voting to close is appropriate; answering is not, if the typo is the only thing you're answering.

Comment: Thank you! I should have caught that. However, there's an error being called well before that with:  
for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {

Comment: @CertainPerformance My answer points out more than just a typo.

Comment: @KellyHook You will find a link in my answer above with a working version of your code.

Comment: @prins  thank-you so much. console.log note appreciated as well.